# Syntax combine two stored procedure into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   [Live].[Test]
 WHERE  [_fk_RoadMapKey] = @_fk_RoadMapKey

 SELECT @TestKey = [TestKey]
 FROM   [Live].[Test]
 WHERE  [_fk_RoadMapKey] = @_fk_RoadMapKey

 SELECT *
 FROM   [Live].[SetofTestGrades]
 WHERE  [_fk_TestKey] = @TestKey
```

the first two statement, can we do get all test as the same time we assign the testkey

```
SELECT * ,@TestKey = [TestKey] FROM [Live].[Test]
    WHERE [_fk_RoadMapKey] = @_fk_RoadMapKey
```

Comment: how is this related to combining two stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign data to a variable and also return data using single select statement, If you are using `@TestKey` to retrieve value from another table then you can skip variable and use join to get data from another table, try this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   [Live].[Test]
 WHERE  [_fk_RoadMapKey] = @_fk_RoadMapKey

 SELECT S.*
 FROM  [Live].[SetofTestGrades] S 
 INNER JOIN [Live].[Test] T ON S.[_fk_TestKey]  = T.[TestKey]
 WHERE  t.[_fk_RoadMapKey] = @_fk_RoadMapKey
```

Comment: whoever down-voted my answer please care to post reason for downvoting?